# Strange behaviour of operator= in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

I have a base class A and two derived classes B and C. B defines the = operator, taking the base class A as parameter.

When calling = on class B, sometimes the operator of base class A is called instead of the one from B.

```
class A {
        public:

        void operator=(A &) {
                printf("A =\n");
        };
};

class B : public A {

        public:

        void operator=(A &s) {
                printf("B =\n");
        };
};

class C : public A {
};

int main()
{
        B b1, b2;
        C c;

        b1 = b2;
        b1 = c;
}
```

Output is:

```
A =
B =
```

- Why is the first assignment not calling B::operator=()?
- Why is the second assignment not calling A::operator=() as well, as it is also derived from A?
- What can i do to make B::operator=() be called every time?

I was totally surprised when i saw this. I noticed it only because i deleted operator=() ("operator=() = delete") in class A, leading to a compiler error.

Comment: Is `B::operator=` supposed to take an `A` instead of a `B`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `B::operator=` is not a copy-assignment operator. In addition to the one you provide, there's also an implicitly-defined copy-assignment operator that is equivalent to

```
B& operator=(const B& other) {
  A::operator=(other);
  return *this;
}
```

This operator doesn't print anything, but it calls the assignment on the base class, and that one prints `A=`.

`b1 = b2` calls this copy-assignment operator. `b1 = c` calls `B::operator=(A&)` since `C` is not a `B`.

If you want your operator to be called, define a copy-assignment operator with the signature shown above, instead of or in addition to the other overload.

Comment: That makes totally sense, thank you.

I tried "B& operator=(const B&) = delete" to trick-force the other operator=(), but unfortunately this doesn't work. But having two operators is not a big problem anyway.

Comment: A function declared deleted still participates in overload resolution. If it's actually chosen, the program is ill-formed.